# Questions involving evaluating the following series

Tags: sequences-and-series, self-learning

I'm wondering if I'm solving the problems below correctly:

> 1. Show that $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k-1} = \ln (\sqrt{n}) + O(1)$$

Given $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = \ln(n) + O(1)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k-1}  + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k}- \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k}$$
$$=\ln(2n) + O(1) - \frac{1}{2}\ln(n)-O(1)= \ln (\sqrt{n})+O(1)$$

> 2. Evaluate $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (2k+1)x^{2k}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (2k+1)x^{2k} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2kx^{2k}+ \sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{2k}$$

Given $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k=\frac{x}{1-x} \qquad \textrm{if } |x|<1$$
I think the second term is:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{2k} = \frac{x^2}{1-x^2}$$

Differentiating the above on both sides and multiplying by $x$,

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2kx^{2k} = \frac{2x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}$$

I added the two terms above and got $$\frac{3x^2-x^4}{(1-x^2)^2}$$

Did I compute this correctly?

Comment: Note that $(2k+1)x^{2k} = (x^{2k+1})'$, then why not just calculate $\sum_1^\infty x^{2k+1}$ then differentiate it?